# Change intent filter android priority of other applications

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver, root

I have a SMS Blocking Android App. It worked fine until Google introduced SMS feature in Hangouts and so did Samsung in its ChatOn messenger. Both of them have the highest priority for SMS receiver ie 2147483647. I verified this from their manifest.
So is there anyway to decrease their SMS receiver priority using what so ever method including root?
I plan to implement a "click to fix" option after a user opens the app.

The only way I could think of doing this was to edit the manifest file of these applications.But again I am not sure how android processes the Broadcast receiver. Does it use its own internal memory to know which app will process the sms received broadcast, or does it read the manifest file of all the installed applications every time?
If there is a separate memory how can I access it(using root, if required) and if manifest file is read every time, is it possible to edit that file even with root, as I read there are signature related issues.

P.S In root programming i have just experimented with calling standard sudo commands inside an app. Also my main focus is on pre Kit Kat devices.

Comment: You can't edit another app manifest without root and if you do it with root you'll break that app's signature so android won't load it.

Comment: So do you agree that Android reads the manifest of all apps that can receive the broadcast every single time??

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're asking whether it reads all app manifests, then yes, it does.

Keep in mind that with the release of KitKat, the SMS system has changed. All SMS are now handled by the OS itself and then SMS apps read the information from the system itself. The old "messenger" app is now just an app, not a datastore as it used to be.

This decouples the SMS system from the stock "messenger" app and allows it to be disabled or uninstalled, and another app (or no app) to take its place.

Older versions still use the messenger app as the SMS data store.

Comment: Yes this is what I am asking. Whenever a SMS is received in pre KitKat devices, does the OS read each and every manifest to check the priorities and decide which app should  receive the Broadcast first.
Thank You.